# Establish http connection through seperate tcp stream

Tags: c++, http, networking, http-headers, tcpclient

I am working on Client Server application. Client side uses Windows Networking API's to establish connection with server. There are many HTTP requests I am requesting,which can use persistent connection. However for one HTTP Request I have to send it through seperate TCP stream,how can I achieve this? Currently my HTTP request is using the already used TCP stream which is causing issue. I have control on client code,so is there any header I can include to make sure http request does not share the connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WinHttpSetOption(handle, WINHTTP_OPTION_MAX_CONNS_PER_SERVER, &maxConnections, 
                 sizeof(maxConnections));
```